# Function returns empty array instead of arguments object when called inside of another method

Tags: javascript

Here's a simple function I invented to test out JavaScript's `argument` object versus rest parameters.

```
function f(a, b, ...theArgs) { 
  console.log(theArgs); 
  console.log(arguments); 
  return arguments;
}
```

if I call this function, say with these parameters: `f(1,2,6,5,8,9,10,'a')`
I'll get two console logs and then the argument objects is returned. All great.

However, if I pass this function to:
`Array.prototype.slice(f(1,2,6,5,8,9,10,'a'), f.length)`, I will get an empty array back instead of an array like `[6,5,8,9,10,'a']`-- it appears that in this case my function is returning an empty array instead of the arguments object.

Why is that? Here's a snapshot of my console:

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `Array.prototype.slice.call`? `Array.prototype` is a special empty array.

Comment: Dangit.. that's what it was. Could you explain in your answer why call needs to be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype` is the empty array that your code is slicing on, not the result of `f`.

The first parameter to [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) must be a number. In your code, `f` returns an object. If you want to change the `this` value of the `slice` function so that it slices your object instead, use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(f(1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 'a'), f.length)
```

```js
function f(a, b, ...theArgs) {
  //console.log(theArgs);
  //console.log(arguments);
  return arguments;
}

console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(f(1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 'a'), f.length));
```